# Group several MPL assertions in a macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, boost-mpl

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
#define VERIFY_EXPECTATIONS       \
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((expectation1)); \
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((expectation2)); \
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((expectation3))
```

and when writing `VERIFY_EXPECTATIONS;` in line, say 42, I get an error about a conflicting declaration of `mpl_assertion_in_line_42`.

I understand what is happening (`BOOST_MPL_ASSERT` uses an identifier that depends on the line where the macro is invoked) but my question is: is there a known workaround to do this kind of things?

Edit:

More precisely, the expectations look like that:

```
#define TEST_SOME_SET_OF_PREDICATES(Arg)          \
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT    ((some_predicate<Arg>));      \
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_NOT((some_other_predicate<Arg>))

TEST_SOME_SET_OF_PREDICATES(some_type);
TEST_SOME_SET_OF_PREDICATES(some_other_type);
```

I have implemented the predicates and I want to test them with several types.

Note:

I'm not very interested in the following:

```
template <typename Arg>
struct compound_predicate : boost::mpl::and_<
    some_predicate<Arg>,
    boost::mpl::not_<some_other_predicate<Arg> >
> {};

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((compound_predicate<some_type>));
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((compound_predicate<some_other_type>));
```

because when an assertion fails, we don't know which of the expectations was wrong.

The solution suggested by Praetorian would be the following:

```
template <typename Arg>
struct expectations {
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT    ((some_predicate<Arg>));
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_NOT((some_other_predicate<Arg>));
};
```

and then instantiate `expectations` with `some_type` and `some_other_type`. I would have to implement a macro that declares an object of type `expectations<Arg>` with a different identifier at each call. It looks a little bit like reimplementing (some part of) static assertions.

Any other ideas?

Comment: wrap each of the mpl macros in `{}`?

Comment: Do not use mpl assert, and instead switch to std::assert? It's 2016, we surely can assume C++11 by default.

Comment: @SergeyA I would be glad to switch to C++11 or C++14 but - believe it or not - we are still using C++03 in my firm (despite my insistence!).

Comment: @user3159253 Nice try, thanks, but it does not work: it results in an `expected unqualified-id before '{' token` error.

Comment: What do these `expectationN` look like? Can you make `VERIFY_EXPECTATIONS` a class template instead, and instantiate it where it's needed?

Comment: @Praetorian See my edit. I can do that: it works, but there is some additional macro to implement in order to instantiate the template with the various types. But maybe this is the simplest solution anyway.